# How to put sql data in php table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to make table in php with three column that display image from the database under each image there should be description of the image. The description is also retrieve from the database. My code now work fine for the image part it display three images next to each other then display the next three images in new row and so on.

However I want something like this:

IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE
DESC  DESC  DESC 
 
IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE
DESC  DESC  DESC

When I uncomment line 26

```
<br/>
( //echo "< td style='background-color:#FF0004'>" . $data. "</td>";)
<br/>
```

I get the description next to the image like this

IMAGE DESC IMAGE DESC IMAGE DESC
IMAGE DESC IMAGE DESC IMAGE DESC

I also tried to start and create new row < tr>< td>< /tr>< /tr> 
after line 50 when the image row is closed and fetch the sql data again but only get the desc but when I did this I got no result (I'm 100% sure that there are data in my sql). How can I get the description to be above the image instead of next to the image

```
function getImg(){
    $conn = connect(); 

    if (!isset($_GET['startrow']) or !is_numeric($_GET['startrow'])) {
        $startrow = 0;
    } else {
        $startrow = (int)$_GET['startrow'];
    }

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM draft LIMIT $startrow, 6";
   $getdata = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) 
        or die(mysqli_error());

    $cell_img = mysqli_num_rows($getdata);
    $i=0;
    $per_row = 3; 
    echo "<table><tr>";

    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getdata)) {
        echo "<td><img src='".$row['image']."'/ ></td>";
        $data = $row['desc'];  
        //echo "<td style='background-color:#FF0004'>" . $data. "</td>";

        if (++$i % $per_row==0 && $i >0 && $i <$cell_img) {
            echo "</tr><tr>"; 
        }                
    }

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "</tr>";

    for ($x=0; $x<$per_row-$i % $per_row; $x++) {  
        echo "<td></td>";       
    }

    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";

    echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?startrow='.($startrow+5).'">Next >>></a>';
    $prev = $startrow - 5;

    if ($prev >= 0)
        echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?startrow='.$prev.'"> <<<< Previous</a>';
}
```

Comment: storing and retrieving images from database is not a good choice.. just saying :)

Comment: Always look at the rendered HTML and you'll see exactly why you get the result you do. Consider using something like `<td><img ... /><br />Description</td>`

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
$data = '';
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getdata)) {
     echo "<td><img src='".$row['image']."'/ ></td>";
     $data .= '<td>'.$row['desc'].'</td>';

     if (++$i % $per_row==0 && $i >0 && $i <= $cell_img) {
          echo "</tr><tr>$data</tr><tr>"; 
          $data = '';
     }
 }
```

Comment: thank you, however this only worked for the first row of images the second for the second row of the image (the other 3 images) it didn't show the desc